# Is reseating passengers a reinforcement learning problem?

Tags: optimization, reinforcement-learning, methodology, artificial-intelligence

Requirement is to optimally move passengers from one seat map to another which has a different configuration.

Move should be based on many rules like -

1) Families should be sitting together

2) Those who were at windows seat should be moved to window seat if available.

3) Kids should be seated at middle seat.

4) and many more..

There are many seat map configurations available and at a time we need to move passengers from one to another as per the requirement.

Is it a reinforcement learning problem ? If yes, how it can be approached.

Comment: Do you get any feedback after the reseating, so that you can adjust the reseating, get feedback, adjust, etc. ?

Comment: @tim,  yes. Feedback can be set based on rules.